# How to handle nested array structure in Redux combineReducers

Tags: redux

ALl:

I'm pretty new to Redux reducer. I wonder if I have a nested array structure data, how can I build that combined reducer even I can normalize the data.

**Any example for this?**

For example, my data structure is like:

```
[
   {
      category:"c1",
      subcategories: [{name: "sc1", items: [{name: "i1"}]}...]
   }
   ...
]
```

How can I turn it into a structure that can apply `combineReducer()`? Thanks